# findOneAndUpdate updates database but hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Problem: My async function does update the database but then does not continue with the rest of the script.

```js
//Process the data after you get it...
async function burnStatus(data) {
  console.log("Burn Data Compiled Saving...");

  let filter = { _id: "5e4454059a0be1c238b5f70b" };

  if (data.error === true) {
    console.log("Error retrieving burn data.");

    var update = { update: burn.date, error: data.error };
  } else {
    var update = {
      date: data.date,
      precipitation: data.precipitation,
      wind: { morning: data.wind.morning, afternoon: data.wind.afternoon },
      ventIndex: data.ventIndex,
      aqi: data.aqi,
      updated: data.updated
    };
  }

  console.log(update);

  let doc = await BURN.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { upsert: true }, (error, result) => {
    // *** NOTHING BELOW HERE EXECUTES EVEN THOUGH THE DB DOES GET UPDATED. ***

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });

  console.log("Burn Data Updated");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Getting Burn Data...
(node:16248) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Response Received Processing...
Precipitation: 0
Morning Wind: 6
Afternoon Wind: 8
Ventilation Index: POOR
AQI: 48
Burn Data Compiled Saving...
{
  date: '02/13/20',
  precipitation: 0,
  wind: { morning: 6, afternoon: 8 },
  ventIndex: 'POOR',
  aqi: 48,
  updated: '2020-02-13T12:42:11.201Z'
}
```

Troubleshooting:

I have managed to track it down to the `let doc = await BURN.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, (error, result) => {` line. I am unable to get it to throw an error for me to catch (or I am not attempting to catch the error correctly).

So I am guessing there isnt an error and I am just doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I would also reccommend reading up on the differences between `callbacks`, `promises` and `await`'s. It will help you a lot in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using both `await` and the callback here `(error, result)`

You need to pick one not both.

## await

```
try {
  let result = await BURN.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {upsert: true});
  console.log("Burn Data Updated")
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

## callback

```
let doc = BURN.findOneAndUpdate(
  filter,
  update,
  { upsert: true },
  (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      console.log("Burn Data Updated");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Jack,
Thank you for your help. I'm still having the same issue. Originally I had just had await and I added the call back to try and catch the error. (Which obviously was the wrong way).

Since then I have changed to the:

```
try {
  let result = await BURN.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {upsert: true});
  console.log("Burn Data Updated")
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```
It still does not log the "Burn Data Updated" or generate an error.

Comment: Disregard my last I believe I have figured it out. I was attempting to troubleshoot this as a module and was loading it separate from my app.js even though my app.js was still running in the background. I restarted app.js and it went through the whole function. Thanks again for the help.